# ¿Como puedo hacer con JS especificamente para la página de un BLOG, la opción de "CARGAR MÁS" y que despliegue más publicaciones del blog.?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Ej: [image: Es esto lo que necesito hacer, si me pueden explicar les agradecería bastante, (NO ES EL BOTON, si no la FUNCION de desplegar más publicaciones)]

Quiero hacer un blog exactamente, pero no se como hacer con JS que con un BOTÓN me traiga más resultados de publicaciones previamente hechas, vale aclarar que lo quiero hacer con HTML, CSS y JS.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir lo que has intentado hasta el momento? Recuerda que es recomendable incluir un [mcve] -tal como se indica en [ask]- con el trabajo hecho al momento y enfocar tus dudas al código elaborado. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más información.

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama *paginado*, y para implementar dicho paginado todo dependerá de la forma en que obtienes la información del servidor. Saludos